# Why did newer compilers start accepting this template function call?

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

The following small C++ program involving a call to the template function `std::atomic_fetch_add()` fails to compile in godbolt for x86-64 clang versions less than 9.0 and gcc versions less than 9.1,
in both cases using the `--std=c++11` option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<char> ch ('@');

int main ()
{
    std::atomic_fetch_add (&ch, 5);
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
}
```

In those early compiler versions (it might be more related to the C++ libraries provided by the compilers, I'm not sure), the `std::atomic_fetch_add (&ch, 5);`  call fails to match any template specialization for the atomic fetch function, since the type of `ch` is `char`, and the type of `5` is `int`:

> : In function 'int main()':
> :8:34: error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_add(std::atomic*, int)'
>     std::atomic_fetch_add (&ch, 5);
> ...

However, later versions of the compiler (& libraries?) successfully compile this usage.

1. What changed to make this start compiling?
2. If it is a standard library change, what technique is used to allow this?
3. Does the C++ standard (& what version?) require that this usage should work.

I'm pretty much a C++ beginner, but I gather that this is related to implicit conversions not being performed as part of figuring out the appropriate template specialization to use. (I may not be using precise language.)

I know that I can modify the call to work by rewriting it as either

```
std::atomic_fetch_add<char> (&ch, 5);
```

or

```
std::atomic_fetch_add (&ch, (char)5);
```

However, I'm interested in getting a version of the `<atomic>` library to support the usage without the explicit instantiation and without the cast. (The compiler is clang 15.0.0, `--std=c++11`.  The library is a proprietary version of the Dinkum libraries.)

I need to understand how to support the calling of template functions like
`std::atomic_fetch_char (&ch, 5)` where the argument types do not exactly match those in the template declaration.  I would, for example, like to understand how this is supported in the linux `/usr/include/c++/11/` standard library.

The nearest I've come up with myself is to add non-template overloads of various instantiations of `std::atomic_fetch_add()` & similar functions, but I don't see that being done in the Linux/GNU C++ libraries and I suspect there is a cleaner way. I want to understand it.

Comment: The behavior of [`std::atomic_fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add) have been retroactively changed in the C++11 standard because of defect report [P0558R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0558r1.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally `std::atomic_fetch_add` required the second parameter to have the same type as the `value_type` of the atomic object as both parameters participated in type deduction.

This was removed with defect report [P0558R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0558r1.pdf) so that deduction only happens on the atomic object and the second parameter is just converted to the `differece_type` of the atomic object.

You get the error because older versions didn't get patched with this defect report but newer versions did.